# Getting error As Mutating method sent to immutable object

Tags: uitableview

I'm using `NSJsonSerilization` to fetch JSON data in `UITableView` cells. I have declared the array as `NSMutableArray`.but still i'm getting

```
-[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object error
```

and application is crashing whenever i'm trying to delete the cells.

```
cell.nameLabel.text = [[jsonResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"FromProviderName"];

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [jsonResults removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [jsonTable reloadData];
}
```

I tried to look up the solutions which were being answered before, I am doing the same things. Thanks!

Comment: can you show us how you are passing values to `jsonResults`?

Comment: jsonResults =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil];
    [jsonTable reloadData];

Answer (score 0):

I hope so you need the function called "mutableCopy" at the end of fetch request.

```
jsonResults = (NSMutableArray*)[[cdc.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy];
```

**Edit according to your comment:**

```
jsonResults = (NSMutableArray*)[[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:nil error:nil] mutableCopy];
```